# Can I declare a compile time constant of a custom type (other than enum)?

Tags: c#, immutability

Consider this type, is it as immutable as I can make it?

```
public struct SomeType
{
    public const int OneValue = 1;

    private static readonly one = new SomeType(one);

    private readonly int value;

    private SomeType(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static One
    {
        get { return this.one; }
    }

    public static implicit operator int(SomeType source)
    {
        return source.value;
    }

    public void SomeSpecialization()
    {
    }
}
```

This allows me to do this,

```
var one = SomeType.One;

switch (one)
{
    case SomeType.OneValue:
        ...
}
```

but, is there anyway I can remove

```
public static implicit operator int(SomeType source)
    {
        return source.value;
    }
```

from the type definition and use the type like this?

```
var one = SomeType.One;

switch (one)
{
    case SomeType.One:
        ...
}
```

Comment: @CuongLe, so that I can extend with `SomeSpecialization`, question altered.

Comment: For some scenarios you can write an extension method for en enum.

Comment: `public static One { ... }` ? `SomeType` or `int` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `case` expressions in a `switch` statement can only be compile-time constants of certain built-in types and `enum`s. So the answer is no: no matter what you do with your `SomeType` (short of turning it into an `enum`), you cannot use `SomeType` objects as `case` expressions.

Comment: To be more correct, they can also be `nullable<T>` where `T` is one of the types I referred to in my answer.

Comment: good spot, I was wondering if there was some way to transfer the magic used for `enum` and `Nullable<T>`, now that 4.5 is out. However, I suspect yours is the right answer.

Comment: This is a language (C#) issue, not a framework (.NET) issue. As of today, there is no specification for C# 5.0, so the C# 4.0 specification still applies. According to section 8.7.2 of the specification, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `Enum`, try static class:

```
public static class SomeType
{
    public const int OneValue = 1;
    public const int SecondValue = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something of this help?

```
public struct SomeType<T> where T : IConvertible
{
    private static readonly T _one = (T)Convert.ChangeType(1, typeof(T));
    public static T One { get { return _one; } }
}
```

Comment: I can achieve this implicitly with the type conversion operator.